# "No longer accepting questions" message on Code Review

Tags: support, ban

I recently posted a question about two days ago and I got voted up three times. But now when I go into Code Review to ask another question, it says that I can no longer ask any questions with this account. I am not sure why this is the case. I am hoping the moderator could remove that hold since I am posting questions that are now being upvoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a large amount of deleted questions.

The only way you can be allowed to post questions again is to edit your old questions and undelete them, give them some time to hopefully be upvoted. Then and only then can you post questions again.

There is nothing a moderator can do about this. The system locked you from asking 
 questions.

You might be able to see your questions here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/76010

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/76010/wolfy?tab=questions&sort=newest